# Can I use variables when using Cloud Storage triggers?

Tags: firebase, triggers, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

When I use Cloud Firestore triggers I can use variables like this:

```
exports.profileCreated = functions.firestore.document('communities_data/{community}/profiles/{profileID}').onCreate((snap, context) => {

//do whatever

});
```

And I can use `community` and `profileID`. Can I do something similar with Cloud Storage triggers? I can't find info about it in the docs.

I need this so I can write the path of the newly uploaded object to it's data in my Cloud Firestore database.
For example, if a new file was uploaded with this path:

`images/ZHpGoD2RAasnOKWlDgCc/restaurant/1200px-I_Love_New_York.svg.png`

I need to be able to extract this part only `ZHpGoD2RAasnOKWlDgCc` so I'll know where to write this new path to, as this is my object's ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcards from Firestore triggers are available in the `context.params` object passed to your function.  The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters) should be clear on how to use this.

Cloud Storage triggers do not have wildcard support.  Any object uploaded to the bucket will trigger the function.  You will have to parse the path of the file using the `name` property of the [ObjectMetadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.storage.ObjectMetadata) that's passed to the function to see if it's a file you're interested in, and extra any data from it.